# Don't get the appropriate div using Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I need to show one div from multiple div's when there are a lot of div's with the same name-

I want to do like the panel- http://www.estalote.com/est_fix/est_web_calc.php

My Html-Php Code--

```
<?php 
    for($i=0; $i < 6; $i ++)
    {
    ?>
    <div class="section">
        <div class="section_top" align="right">
            <button class="press"> + </button>
        </div>
        <div class="section_mid">
                <p style="padding-bottom:10px;color:BLUE;"><b><font size="3">Rhojhsdkjf</font></b></p>
                <p><input type="radio" name="same"/> Database value 1</p>
                <p><input type="radio" name="same"/> Database value 2</p>
                <p><input type="radio" name="same"/> Database value 3</p>
                <p><input type="radio" name="same"/> Database value 4</p>
            <div class="cleaner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="section_bottom">
        </div>
    </div>     
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

My jQuery Code--

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $( ".press").click(function() {
            $(".section_mid").css("height", "20px");            
            $(".section_mid", this).css("height", "auto");
        });
    });
</script>
```

By default the height of the div is 20px and when i click on the press button i need to show the full height.

Now what to do??
Please help me...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`section_mid` is not a child of `press` thus your code is not working. You need to traverse the DOM correctly.

*Use*

```
$(this).closest('.section').find(".section_mid").css("height", "auto");
```

instead of

```
$(".section_mid", this).css("height", "auto");
```

References

1. [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)
2. [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)